# Can we do restoration using full backup on secondary and , differential and log backup on primary?

Tags: sql-server, backup, availability-groups

i have strange requirement in my environment but i need to ask this question to meet the business objective.

Can we do restoration using full backup on secondary and differential and log backup on primary?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

> Can we do restoration using full backup on secondary and differential and log backup on primary?

Currently, full backups taken on a secondary must be `copy_only` and thus cannot be used as the base for a differential restore. So the answer is, not currently, no.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer